# Laravel: Redirect with post route

Tags: php, laravel

Been trying to find a way to call to pass a multidimensional array to a Post route with no success.

The array looks like this:

```
    "order" => array:16 [
        "id" => "1"
        "total" => "4825"
        "neighborhood" => "Barrio Bravo"
      ]
      "products" => array:2 [
        4 => array:4 [
          "id" => "4"
          "name" => "Maestro Dobel 750ml"
          "price" => "530"
          "quantity" => "1"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [
          "id" => "1"
          "name" => "Don Julio 70 700ml"
          "price" => "650"
          "quantity" => "1"
        ]
      ]
      "grandTotal" => "1180"
      "balanceToPay" => "354"
      "cartTotal" => "826"
```

I don't have any problem asserting the route in the `unit test` calling the route like so:

```
$this->post(route('order.success', $orderInfo));
```

But when it comes to the controller I can't find the way to redirect to `order.success` with its `orderInfo` array.

This won't work since `redirect` only works with `GET`:

```
return redirect(route('order.success', $orderInfo));
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to work with a simple redirection because you cannot choose the HTTP method. It's always GET when you make a redirection. It works in your test because you make a POST request manually.

I can see 2 solutions:

1. You can send data using GET method (they are added as URL parameters). If they are not confidential it can be a solution.
2. If you don't want to send those data in the URL, you have to save them somewhere and get them from the storage when you're on the order.success page. You can save them, for instance, in the session storage or in the local storage of your browser.

Also, your test isn't good if it tests a behavior that does not happen in your app (post request instead of redirection).

Comment: I've tried using GET route as param but I'm getting this error `Array to string conversion`. I'm not quite sure that an array can be passed as parameter. I might try the approach of storing somewhere the information and trying to fetch it once I've been redirected with a GET nout. Not ideal, but it might work.

Comment: @FerToasted yup, I think it's the best and the safest way to handle such an issue. You did not mention how big your array can be so just bear in mind that both session and local storages have content size limits, but they are quite high.